# Performance improvement of a DB view in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, performance

I am trying to work on the performance of this view. I think Materialized view could help but I am wondering if the query can be improved.

```
Primary keys fro the tables are:
CONSUMER_DTL :ID
CONSUMER__HDR : ID
PARTICIPANT : ID
P_DEVICE : ID

   CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW "V_TRANSACTION_HISTORY" ("ID", "TRANSACTION_DATE", "TRANSACTION_ID", "REFUND_AMOUNT", "STATUS", "LABEL_ID", "COST_ID", "CONSUMER_ID") AS 
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CH.ID) AS ID,
               CH.TRANSACTED_ON AS TRANSACTION_DATE,
               CH.ID AS TRANSACTION_ID,
               SUM(CD.GROSS_AMOUNT) AS REFUND_AMOUNT,
               CH.STATUS AS STATUS,
               CH.LABEL_ID,
               S.ID AS COST_ID,
               CH.CONSUMER_ID
       FROM CONSUMER_DTL CD,
            CONSUMER__HDR CH,
            P_DEVICE P,
            PARTICIPANT S
       WHERE CH.ID=CD.TRANSACTION_ID
         AND CH.P_DEVICE_ID=P.ID
         AND P.ID=S.ID
             GROUP BY CH.ID,
                   CH.STATUS,
                   CH.LABEL_ID,
                   CH.TRANSACTED_ON,
                   CH.CONSUMER_ID,
                   S.ID;
```

Comment: First, you should use SQL standard - `inner join ... on ...` Everything else - we don't know. We don't know how much data you have, table keys/indexes.. Other than that, query optimizer will optimize it anyways for you

Comment: Your query does not use any `WHERE` condition, you select **all** data of your table. Thus there is not so much you can improve.

Comment: You could potentially have an index on `consumer_dtl` (`transaction_id`, `gross_amount`), which might help a bit. It should allow the join to the consumer_dtl table to go straight from the index.